# Calling a function to feed an .attr() in d3

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js

I have `.attr` that create my link paths in d3 as below, Lines 42 in the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-cneh8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fzoomable.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts):

```
link.each(function (d){})
  .attr('x1', function (d) {
    return d.source.x;
  })
  .attr('y1', function (d) {
    return d.source.y;
  })
  .attr('x2', function (d) {
    return d.target.x;
  })
  .attr('y2', function (d) {
    return d.target.y;
  });
```

The above draws my path links. I've changed this to calculate making the link paths smaller. However, there is a lot of repeated logic and not sure how to call a function to return my the values required. As below:

```
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      // Total difference in x and y from source to target
      let diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
      let diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

      // Length of path from center of source node to center of target node
      let pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

      // x and y distances from center to outside edge of target node
      let offsetX = (diffX * 40) / pathLength;
      return d.source.x + offsetX;
    }).attr("y1", function(d) {
      let diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
      let diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

      let pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

      let offsetY = (diffY * 40) / pathLength;

      return d.source.y + offsetY;
    }).attr("x2", function(d) {
      let diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
      let diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

      let pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

      let offsetX = (diffX * 40) / pathLength;

      return d.target.x - offsetX;
    }).attr("y2", function(d) {
      let diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
      let diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

      let pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

      let offsetY = (diffY * 40) / pathLength;

      return d.target.y - offsetY;
    })
```

It returns `offsetX` for `d.source.x`/`d.target.x` values and `offsetY` for `d.source.y`/`d.target.y`.

Ideally i dont want all this repeated logic and have tried doing a `.call()` on the link which goes into a function but then I dont know how to return the result into the attributes themselves e.g.

```
  .attr('x1', function (d) {
    return d.source.x; //function return from .call()
  })
```

I've also tried putting the function call within the above attribute but get an error of "is not a function" e.g

```
  .attr('x1', function (d) {
    return this.myNewPathFunction(d); 
  })
```

Lines 42 in the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-cneh8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fzoomable.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: So you don;t want to write repeated logic if I'm understanding it correctly?

Comment: thats right... as you can see there is a lot of it for each attribute. Needs pulling into a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [move your logic](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-2fenub?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fzoomable.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to a function like so:

```js
const coordinate = (position, d, index, nodes) => {
  // Total difference in x and y from source to target
  let diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
  let diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

  // Length of path from center of source node to center of target node
  let pathLength = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

  // x and y distances from center to outside edge of target node
  let offsetX = (diffX * 40) / pathLength;
  let offsetY = (diffY * 40) / pathLength;

  if (position === 'x1') return d.source.x + offsetX;
  if (position === 'y1') return d.source.y + offsetY;
  if (position === 'x2') return d.target.x - offsetX;
  if (position === 'y2') return d.target.y - offsetY;
};

link
  .attr('x1', (d, i, nodes) => coordinate('x1', d, i, nodes))
  .attr('y1', (d, i, nodes) => coordinate('y1', d, i, nodes))
  .attr('x2', (d, i, nodes) => coordinate('x2', d, i, nodes))
  .attr('y2', (d, i, nodes) => coordinate('y2', d, i, nodes));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your objective is both writing less lines of repetitive code **and** reducing the amount of calculations needed.

One of the idiomatic D3 solutions is using `selection.each()`;

Thus, in your case:

```
link.each(d, i, n) {
  // Total difference in x and y from source to target
  let diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
  let diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

  // Length of path from center of source node to center of target node
  let pathLength = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

  // x and y distances from center to outside edge of target node
  let offsetX = (diffX * 40) / pathLength;
  let offsetY = (diffY * 40) / pathLength;

  d3.select(n[i])
    .attr("x1", d.source.x + offsetX)
    .attr("y1", d.source.y + offsetY)
    .attr("x2", d.target.x - offsetX)
    .attr("y2", d.target.y - offsetY);
};
```

Note that the computation of `offsetX` and `offsetY` happens only once per element. In your specific case it's not a heavy computation, but when it is it's a good idea reducing the burden on the browser.